# Build triangle number pattern PHP

Tags: php, design-patterns

I've encountered issue. I was able to build different patterns prev. However, I wasn't able to figure out how to produce script with nessessary output.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7
    1 2 3 4 5 6
      1 2 3 4 5
        1 2 3 4
          1 2 3
            1 2
              1
?>
    <?php  
    for($a=8;$a>=1;$a--){  
    for($b=1;$b<=$a;$b++){  
    echo $b. ' ';  
    }  
    echo "<br>";  
    }
    ?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your question look like home work .. do some more effort

Comment: Thanks for reacting. It is a part of homework. After researching and completing other parts of homework I wasn't able to comprehend that pattern. Thought that software forum might be a good help. Thanks for your time.

Comment: we will help you but you do some more effort and write some more code. if you will face some issues then share code with us and stackoverflow community help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution for this. Check below code.

```
for($a=8;$a>=1; $a--) {
    for($c=$a;$c<=8;$c++) {
        // echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        echo '  ';
    }
    for($b=1;$b<=$a;$b++) {
        echo $b;
    }
    echo "<br />";
}
```

If space doesn't work than try commented part.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much. I didn't realize that I should use $c . Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
       <?php
        $z = 1;
        for( $a=8;$a>=1;$a--){  
            for($b=1;$b<=$a;$b++){  
                echo b." ";  
            }
            if($a!=1){
                echo "<br>";
                $i = 0;
                while($i<$z){
                    echo "  ";
                    $i++;
                }
                $z++;
            }
        }
       ?>
```